# I have to clean my laptop fans every 1 to 2 days

Tags: laptop, fan, noise, cleaning

I have a gaming laptop, to be specific its a acer nitro 5. Every one to two day's I have to open it, clean it, and sometimes i put some WD 40 to make it less noisy. Sometimes the fan blades start to shake. I dont know what to do, I clean it every now and again. But still it always does the same thing, shake or make loud noises.

Comment: Sounds like you should replace the fan.  A repair shop should be able to find a compatible part.

Comment: Any "fix" short of replacing the fan is to be considered suspect. The bearing is worn out, the blades are shaking because the bearing is worn out and the only way to replace the bearing is likely to destroy the fan. Lubricant may stop the noise by making things move more easily, but it is absolutely not a fix for the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

WD-40 is not a lubricant. Perhaps try either some machine oil or graphite to lubricate it, depending on what looks appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

As Connor Nicholson said, WD-40 is not a lubricant. However, if using proper lubricant does not help, the fan bearings might be worn out and need to be replaced.

Comment: What lubricant would you guys recommend I get?

Comment: probably sewing machine oil, since it's designed for parts moving at high speeds.